# Breezingform on joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.1, breezingforms

Im currently using joomla 3.1 with breezingform lite build 818 extension.
Ive already created a form. I want to use the article title as the form title. I've already tried using this `<?php return JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle(); ?>`as value of the text field. But this command only returns the form title. A few pages are using this one form so I need to know which one is from which page. Btw, ive already search and posted in their forums but no reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am from crosstec, sorry that we missed you.

What you need is the browser title:

Go to Form -> Advanced -> More Options -> Pieces -> After Form -> Click "custom" -> add this

```
echo '<script>ff_getElementByName("NAMEOFHIDDEN").value = document.title;</script>';
```

NAMEOFHIDDEN would be the name of a hidden input field that you can create to store the current document title to.

Regards,
Markus